# Creating a SUM of nested object values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, for-loop

I'm using the following code to query an API, which is working well to return nested values in JSON:

```
const obj = response.data.map(function(item) {

return [item.id, item.jobNumber];
});
```

Example JSON:

```
{
 "data": [
  {
     "id": 100,
     "jobNumber": 1,
     "jobTasks": [
        {
           "id": 12,
           "cost": {
              "amountString": 100
           },
           {
           "id": 13,
           "cost": {
              "amountString": 500
           }
         }
     }
  ]
},
  {
     "id": 101,
     "jobNumber": 2,
     "jobTasks": [
        {
           "id": 14,
           "cost": {
              "amountString": 100
           },
          {
           "id": 15,
           "cost": {
              "amountString": 200
           }
         }
     }]

}]
}
```

I'm wanting to now loop through the nested Job Tasks, and SUM the **item.jobTasks.cost.amountString** for each job, So that the following could be returned:

- JobNumber1: Task Costs: 600
- JobNumber2: Task Costs: 300

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `Array#map()` to create a new array and `Array#reduce()` to sum the `amountString`

```js
const apiJson = {"data":[{"id":100,"jobNumber":1,"jobTasks":[{"id":12,"cost":{"amountString":100}},{"id":13,"cost":{"amountString":500}}]},{"id":101,"jobNumber":2,"jobTasks":[{"id":14,"cost":{"amountString":100}},{"id":15,"cost":{"amountString":200}}]}]};

const output = apiJson.data.map(d=>({
  jobNumber : d.jobNumber,
  tasksCost : d.jobTasks.reduce((a,b)=>a.cost.amountString+b.cost.amountString)
}));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `reduce` method which accepts a `callback` method.

Also, use `forEach` method in order to iterate `data` items.

```js
var json={
 "data": [
  {
     "id": 100,
     "jobNumber": 1,
     "jobTasks": [
           {
           "id": 12,
           "cost": {
              "amountString": 100
            }
           },
           {
           "id": 13,
           "cost": {
              "amountString": 500
            }
           }
      ]
  },
  {
     "id": 101,
     "jobNumber": 2,
     "jobTasks": [
          {
           "id": 14,
           "cost": {
              "amountString": 100
           }
           },
          {
           "id": 15,
           "cost": {
              "amountString": 200
           }
          }
    ]

}]
}
json.data.forEach(function(item){
  var sum=item.jobTasks.reduce(function(sum,elem){
     return sum+elem.cost.amountString;
  },0);
   console.log('jobNumber'+item.jobNumber+' '+sum);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

first Update your json , "}" is missing from jobTasks of second object of array data :

```
   "jobTasks": [    { "id": 14,
                    "cost": {
                         "amountString": 100 
                           }
                     },
                     {
                      "id": 15,
                  "cost": {
                        "amountString": 200
                          }
                       }
                ]
```

Now To get Output:

i = 0,1

item.jobTasks[i]cost.amountString;

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). We use it for most of our data processing now. It does take a moment to wrap your head around though as it is versatile.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const getCounts = (data) => objectScan(['data[*].jobTasks[*].cost.amountString'], {
  filterFn: ({ parents, value, context }) => {
    const jobNumber = parents[3].jobNumber;
    context[jobNumber] = (context[jobNumber] || 0) + value;
  }
})(data, {});

const apiJson = { data: [{ id: 100, jobNumber: 1, jobTasks: [{ id: 12, cost: { amountString: 100 } }, { id: 13, cost: { amountString: 500 } }] }, { id: 101, jobNumber: 2, jobTasks: [{ id: 14, cost: { amountString: 100 } }, { id: 15, cost: { amountString: 200 } }] }] };

console.log(getCounts(apiJson));
// => { '1': 600, '2': 300 }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)