# How to iterate through an array of objects and sum a specific property with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects and I need to scroll through them and add Maria and Cristiano's battlesWon, in the end I need to display how many BattleWon each one won as shown in the example

```
 const array = [
      {
        id: '147acaa3-363c-4a28-af43-fcc035a1d500',
        arena: 'Philippine Arena',
        firstParticipant: {
          address: '0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075661',
          name: 'Cristiano',
          battlesWon: 0
        },
        secondParticipant: {
          address: '0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075644',
          name: 'Maria',
          battlesWon: 1
        },
        logs: [ [Object] ]
      },
      {
        id: 'b2ef2d28-d84d-4cc9-946f-3d57b8ce05ab',
        arena: 'Greensboro Coliseum',
        firstParticipant: {
          address: '0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075644',
          name: 'Maria',
          battlesWon: 1
        },
        secondParticipant: {
          address: '0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075661',
          name: 'Cristiano',
          battlesWon: 0
        },
        logs: [ [Object] ]
      }
    ]
```

Expected:

```
{
  Cristiano: 0,
  Maria: 2
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a SUM of nested object values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43753029/creating-a-sum-of-nested-object-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to go through each entry in your data, and then write participant data into the accumulator. The advantage is that you don't need to create a separate object outside your function.

Then, in each iteration of the `reduce()`, you simply use a generic function that writes participant data into the accumulator:

```
function handleParticipant(participant, acc) {
  const { name, battlesWon } = participant;
  acc[name] = (acc[name] || 0) + battlesWon;
}
```

The real logic is in the line `acc[name] = (acc[name] || 0) + battlesWon`, that basically says: if `name` is found in the dictionary, then add `battlesWon` to its value, otherwise you add `battlesWon` to a starting value of `0`.

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: '147acaa3-363c-4a28-af43-fcc035a1d500',
    arena: 'Philippine Arena',
    firstParticipant: {
      address: '0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075661',
      name: 'Cristiano',
      battlesWon: 0
    },
    secondParticipant: {
      address: '0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075644',
      name: 'Maria',
      battlesWon: 1
    }
  },
  {
    id: 'b2ef2d28-d84d-4cc9-946f-3d57b8ce05ab',
    arena: 'Greensboro Coliseum',
    firstParticipant: {
      address: '0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075644',
      name: 'Maria',
      battlesWon: 1
    },
    secondParticipant: {
      address: '0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075661',
      name: 'Cristiano',
      battlesWon: 0
    }
  }
];

function handleParticipant(participant, acc) {
  const { name, battlesWon } = participant;
  acc[name] = (acc[name] || 0) + battlesWon;
}

const battlesWonByName = data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const { firstParticipant, secondParticipant } = cur;
  
  handleParticipant(firstParticipant, acc);
  handleParticipant(secondParticipant, acc);
  
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(battlesWonByName);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think one possible solution is to loop over the array using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and then adding the values to a results dictionary, as you can see here:

```js
let list = [
    {
        id: '147acaa3-363c-4a28-af43-fcc035a1d500',
        arena: 'Philippine Arena',
        firstParticipant: {
            address: '0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075661',
            name: 'Cristiano',
            battlesWon: 0
        },
        secondParticipant: {
            address: '0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075644',
            name: 'Maria',
            battlesWon: 1
        },
        logs: [[Object]]
    },
    {
        id: 'b2ef2d28-d84d-4cc9-946f-3d57b8ce05ab',
        arena: 'Greensboro Coliseum',
        firstParticipant: {
            address: '0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075644',
            name: 'Maria',
            battlesWon: 1
        },
        secondParticipant: {
            address: '0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075661',
            name: 'Cristiano',
            battlesWon: 0
        },
        logs: [[Object]]
    }
]

let results = {
    Cristiano: 0,
    Maria: 0
}

list.forEach(arena => {
    results[arena.firstParticipant.name] += arena.firstParticipant.battlesWon
    results[arena.secondParticipant.name] += arena.secondParticipant.battlesWon
})

console.log(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: '147acaa3-363c-4a28-af43-fcc035a1d500',
    arena: 'Philippine Arena',
    firstParticipant: {
      address: '0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075661',
      name: 'Cristiano',
      battlesWon: 0
    },
    secondParticipant: {
      address: '0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075644',
      name: 'Maria',
      battlesWon: 1
    },
    logs: [ [Object] ]
  },
  {
    id: 'b2ef2d28-d84d-4cc9-946f-3d57b8ce05ab',
    arena: 'Greensboro Coliseum',
    firstParticipant: {
      address: '0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075644',
      name: 'Maria',
      battlesWon: 1
    },
    secondParticipant: {
      address: '0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075661',
      name: 'Cristiano',
      battlesWon: 0
    },
    logs: [ [Object] ]
  }
]

let result = {};

arr.forEach(val => {
  ['firstParticipant', 'secondParticipant'].forEach(key => {
    if(result.hasOwnProperty(val[key]['name'])) {
      result[val[key]['name']] += val[key]['battlesWon'];
    } else {
      result[val[key]['name']] = val[key]['battlesWon'];
    }
  })
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```js
const json = [
  {
    id: '147acaa3-363c-4a28-af43-fcc035a1d500',
    arena: 'Philippine Arena',
    firstParticipant: {
      address: '0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075661',
      name: 'Cristiano',
      battlesWon: 0
    },
    secondParticipant: {
      address: '0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075644',
      name: 'Maria',
      battlesWon: 1
    },
    logs: [ [Object] ]
  },
  {
    id: 'b2ef2d28-d84d-4cc9-946f-3d57b8ce05ab',
    arena: 'Greensboro Coliseum',
    firstParticipant: {
      address: '0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075644',
      name: 'Maria',
      battlesWon: 1
    },
    secondParticipant: {
      address: '0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075661',
      name: 'Cristiano',
      battlesWon: 0
    },
    logs: [ [Object] ]
  }
]

var newJson = new Array();
json.map((battle) => {
    newJson[battle.firstParticipant.name] = newJson[battle.firstParticipant.name] != null ? battle.firstParticipant.battlesWon + newJson[battle.firstParticipant.name] :  battle.firstParticipant.battlesWon;
    newJson[battle.secondParticipant.name] = newJson[battle.secondParticipant.name] != null ? battle.secondParticipant.battlesWon + newJson[battle.secondParticipant.name] :  battle.secondParticipant.battlesWon;
});
```

Comment: use `.forEach` instead of `.map`. Map returns new array, but foreach itarates through  array elements

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve the result using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { firstParticipant: { name: a, battlesWon: m }, secondParticipant: { name: b, battlesWon: n } } = curr;
  acc[a] = (acc[a] ?? 0) + m
  acc[b] = (acc[b] ?? 0) + n
  return acc;
}, {});
```

**1)**

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: "147acaa3-363c-4a28-af43-fcc035a1d500",
    arena: "Philippine Arena",
    firstParticipant: {
      address: "0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075661",
      name: "Cristiano",
      battlesWon: 0,
    },
    secondParticipant: {
      address: "0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075644",
      name: "Maria",
      battlesWon: 1,
    },
    logs: [[Object]],
  },
  {
    id: "b2ef2d28-d84d-4cc9-946f-3d57b8ce05ab",
    arena: "Greensboro Coliseum",
    firstParticipant: {
      address: "0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075644",
      name: "Maria",
      battlesWon: 1,
    },
    secondParticipant: {
      address: "0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075661",
      name: "Cristiano",
      battlesWon: 0,
    },
    logs: [[Object]],
  },
];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const {
    firstParticipant: { name: name1, battlesWon: battlesWon1 },
    secondParticipant: { name: name2, battlesWon: battlesWon2 },
  } = curr;

  acc[name1] ? (acc[name1] += battlesWon1) : (acc[name1] = battlesWon1);
  acc[name2] ? (acc[name2] += battlesWon2) : (acc[name2] = battlesWon2);

  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

**2)**

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: "147acaa3-363c-4a28-af43-fcc035a1d500",
    arena: "Philippine Arena",
    firstParticipant: {
      address: "0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075661",
      name: "Cristiano",
      battlesWon: 0,
    },
    secondParticipant: {
      address: "0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075644",
      name: "Maria",
      battlesWon: 1,
    },
    logs: [[Object]],
  },
  {
    id: "b2ef2d28-d84d-4cc9-946f-3d57b8ce05ab",
    arena: "Greensboro Coliseum",
    firstParticipant: {
      address: "0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075644",
      name: "Maria",
      battlesWon: 1,
    },
    secondParticipant: {
      address: "0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075661",
      name: "Cristiano",
      battlesWon: 0,
    },
    logs: [[Object]],
  },
];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, { firstParticipant, secondParticipant }) => {
  acc[firstParticipant.name]
    ? (acc[firstParticipant.name] += firstParticipant.battlesWon)
    : (acc[firstParticipant.name] = firstParticipant.battlesWon);

  acc[secondParticipant.name]
    ? (acc[secondParticipant.name] += secondParticipant.battlesWon)
    : (acc[secondParticipant.name] = secondParticipant.battlesWon);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nodeJs and you have an additional 'Johnn' to check this will be

useful

```
import lodash  from 'lodash';
const arr = [
    {
      id: "147acaa3-363c-4a28-af43-fcc035a1d500",
      arena: "Philippine Arena",
      firstParticipant: {
        address: "0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075661",
        name: "Cristiano",
        battlesWon: 0,
      },
      secondParticipant: {
        address: "0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075644",
        name: "Maria",
        battlesWon: 1,
      },
      logs: [[Object]],
    },
    {
      id: "b2ef2d28-d84d-4cc9-946f-3d57b8ce05ab",
      arena: "Greensboro Coliseum",
      firstParticipant: {
        address: "0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075644",
        name: "John",
        battlesWon: 1,
      },
      secondParticipant: {
        address: "0x3ba59bcc1a02cb46e7de35fb0bacc860bf075661",
        name: "Cristiano",
        battlesWon: 0,
      },
      logs: [[Object]],
    },
  ];

const input = ['Cristiano', 'Maria', 'John'];
const attr = [{
    selector: 'firstParticipant.name',
    sum: 'firstParticipant.battlesWon'
},{
    selector: 'secondParticipant.name',
    sum: 'secondParticipant.battlesWon'
}];

function getResult(arr, attr, input) {
    let result = {};
    arr.forEach((obj) => {
        attr.forEach((param)=>{
            let index = input.indexOf(lodash.get(obj, param.selector));
            let value = lodash.get(obj, param.sum);
            if( index > -1) {
                result[input[index]] = result[input[index]] ? (result[input[index]] + value) : value;
            }
        });
    });
    return result;
}
console.log(getResult(arr, attr, input));
```